# Angular 2/4 choose router outlet at runtime

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a child `<router-outlet>` inside a template that displays various components, based on the menu item clicked. Each child component is responsive, and handles itself well when resizing the page.

The problem is the parent component. In desktop view we need it to be one way, (flexboxes) and in mobile we need it to be another way. What this boils down to is where we put the `<router-outlet>`.

The obvious solution is to have a couple of `<div>`s whose classes are set with `display: none/block` conditionally with a `@media` query.

And here is where I'm stuck. Angular always chooses the most nested `<router-outlet>` to use for children. Even though the other one technically no longer exists in the DOM (`display: none`), the router renders the component inside that outlet.

I looked at named router outlets, but that needs to be set at compile time, in the router config. I need to decide at runtime which outlet to render, based on screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is (currently) impossible.
Angular will always choose the most-nested `<router-outlet>` to house the components, there is no way to determine at runtime.
My workaround was to use an unholy fusion of `display: flex`, `display: grid` and `@media` queries to move the `<router-outlet>` around the page, using CSS to determine where it will appear.